# Passing json object to python using angularjs

Tags: javascript, python, json, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and python and I have this problem. I've been trying to pass in the data of a form to Python server side using angularjs. I've converted the form to a json object before sending it over in my .js controller.

controller.js:

```
    jsonObj = this.form.toJson;
    $xhr('POST','/form/processform',jsonObj,function() {
        alert("Done!");
        window.load("/");
    }, function(){
        "Request failed";
    });
```

Python:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import simplejson as json

class processForm(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        form = json.loads(self.request.body)
        # process forms 
        self.redirect("#/")#redirects to main page
```

I recieved an error called "JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded". I've tried to replace the 'POST' to 'JSON' but it does not seem to work as well. I've also read up on $resource in angularjs, but i'm not sure how to use it.

Is this because of the wrong usage of $xhr? Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Try to print on the console variable **self.request.body** it should be purely json-string if it's json.loads should work.

Comment: Examine the structure of your post request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording to `JSONDecodeError` the `jsonObj` variable is not containing a valid JSON object.

I believe problem is here:

```
jsonObj = this.form.toJson;
```

You shoud call the `toJson` method instead of assiging it to a variable:

```
jsonObj = angular.toJson(this.form);
```

Comment: hmm.. it still does not seem to work. I got an error saying that obj has no method 'toJSON'. Is there any library i have to import?

Comment: I've modified the code snippet. See reference: http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/api/angular.toJson

Comment: Yup! It works! Thanks so much! Just to clarify though, why does replacing 'JSON' in $xhr not work? When would we use this instead of 'POST' or 'GET'? Sorry, I can't seem to find much information on this.

Comment: `POST` and `GET` are HTTP methods (=types of messages). It has nothing to do with JSON (which is the encoding of data inside of the HTTP request/response)